# jplayer streaming stopping because no data for few second (or miliseconds)

Tags: vlc, jplayer, icecast

i have vlc which stream mp3 to a icecast server.
when vlc has finished one file, it stops( --play-and-exit)

when the client is vlc, the stream keeps going.
if i use jplayer, it stops after the first song.

How can i make jplayer not timing out?

regards:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var stream = {
        title: "ABC Jazz",
        oga: "http://streaming.yyy.com:8000/flux.ogg"
    },
    ready = false;

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            ready = true;
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream);
        },
        pause: function() {
            $(this).jPlayer("clearMedia");
        },
        error: function(event) {

                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream).jPlayer("play");

        },
        swfPath: "../js",
        supplied: "oga",
        preload: "none",
        wmode: "window",
        keyEnabled: true
    });


    $("#jplayer_inspector").jPlayerInspector({jPlayer:$("#jquery_jplayer_1")});
});
```

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the station.  A broken station configuration will disconnect users in between media switches.  You might not notice this in VLC because VLc will transparently reconnect when the connection is lost.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem